# Discord.py - Make a bot react to its own message(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make my discord bot react to its own message, pretty much. The system works like this:

A person uses the command !!bug - And gets a message in DM', she/she is supposed to answer those questions. And then whatever he/she answered, it will be transferred an embedded message to an admin text-channel.

But I need to add 3 emojis, or react with three different emojis. And depending on what the admin chooses, it will transfer the message once more. So if an admin reacts to an emoji that equals to "fixed", it will be moved to a "fixed" text-channel (the entire message).

I have done a lot of research about this, but only found threads about the old discord.py, meaning
`await bot.add_react(emoji)` - But as I have understood it, that no longer works!

Here is my code:

`````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

TOKEN = '---'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!')

reactions = [":white_check_mark:", ":stop_sign:", ":no_entry_sign:"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')


@bot.command()
async def bug(ctx, desc=None, rep=None):
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.author.send('```Please explain the bug```')
    responseDesc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    description = responseDesc.content
    await ctx.author.send('````Please provide pictures/videos of this bug```')
    responseRep = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    replicate = responseRep.content
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bug Report', color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name='Description', value=description, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Replicate', value=replicate, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Reported By', value=user, inline=True)
    adminBug = bot.get_channel(733721953134837861)
    await adminBug.send(embed=embed)
    # Add 3 reaction (different emojis) here

bot.run(TOKEN)
`````

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In discord.py@rewrite, you have to use [`discord.Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction):

```py
emojis = ['emoji 1', 'emoji_2', 'emoji 3']
adminBug = bot.get_channel(733721953134837861)
message = await adminBug.send(embed=embed)

for emoji in emojis:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Then, to exploit reactions, you'll have to use the [`discord.on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.on_reaction_add) event. This event will be triggered when someone reacts to a message and will return a [`Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.Reaction) object and a [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User) object:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    embed = reaction.embeds[0]
    emoji = reaction.emoji

    if user.bot:
        return

    if emoji == "emoji 1":
        fixed_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await fixed_channel.send(embed=embed)
    elif emoji == "emoji 2":
        #do stuff
    elif emoji == "emoji 3":
        #do stuff
    else:
        return
```

---

NB: You'll have to replace `"emoji 1"`, `"emoji  2"` and `"emoji 3"` with your emojis. `add_reactions` accepts:

- Global emojis (eg. ) that you can copy on [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/)
- Raw unicode (as you tried)
- [Discord emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message): `\N{EMOJI NAME}`
- Custom [discord emojis](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=emoji#discord.Emoji) (There might be some better ways, I've came up with this after a small amount a research)

  ```py
  async def get_emoji(guild: discord.Guild, arg):
       return get(ctx.guild.emojis, name=arg)
  ```

Comment: Ahhh, I see! But when it comes to adding emojis, I am using non-custom emojis for this, but still get the error that it is an `unknown emoji`, what do I write? Trying with `:white_check_mark:`. And well, taking it from my `emojis` array.

Comment: Ahh! I tried using raw unicode, and it works fine now! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add non custom emojis you need to add its id and name into a format that discord.py can read: `<:emoji name:emoji id>`

For example, the white and green check emoji that is a discord default emoji...
you would need to write `<:white_check_mark:824906654385963018>` for discord.py to be able to identify it.