# How to add reaction to a message that bot sends in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

My code is like this, I want it to send a message and react to it, but after running it, nothing happens in the channel, and there's no error either.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    Channel = client.get_channel(775355712271941647)
    Text = "React to get role"
    moji = await Channel.send(Text)
    await moji.add_reaction(emoji='')
```

Comment: Does your bot have permission to send messages, add reactions and also access to the channel? are you using bot or client?  There isn't anything wrong with the code itself.

Comment: what intents have you enabled?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py - Make a bot react to its own message(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960775/discord-py-make-a-bot-react-to-its-own-messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem is I have two `on_ready`, and I should also use `bot.event` instead of `client.event` (because I named the client as bot).

So the following code would work if you have same problem as me:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    moji = await bot.get_channel(775355712271941647).send("bot is online")
    await moji.add_reaction(emoji='')
```